# Preg Match anything between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I have to get the location of a number from this site

lookupexpert.com/search_phone?phone_number=7322691678

And i want a regex that matches anything inside

```
<p class="location">OCEAN GATE, NJ</p>
```

How do i do that?

This is what i did so far

```
<?php

$subject = file_get_contents("http://lookupexpert.com/search_phone?phone_number=7322691678");

$pattern = '#\<p class="location"\>(.+?)\<\/p\>#s';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

and also ... i tried with Xpath, and didn't worked so good, because it is not properly validated

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/p[4]
```

Comment: [You shouldn't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better not to rely on unreliable regex parsing the HTML and use a DOM parser instead. Use a code like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
// assuming search_phone.html contains your saved HTML source
#$doc->loadHTMLFile('search_phone.html'); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$value = $xpath->evaluate("string(//li[starts-with(@class, 'recordItem')]/
                           p[@class='location']/text())"); 
echo "Location Name: [$value]\n"; // prints your location
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Location Name: [OCEAN GATE, NJ]
```

Comment: it works, thanks, but what are you doing there with xpath "string(//li[@class='recordItem clearfix']/
                           p[@class='location']/text())" ...... i mean why "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/p[4]" is not correct? its from mozilla, and second, why xpath instead regex? thank you

Comment: Actually `$xpath->evaluate("string(/html/body/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/p[4]/text())")` also works fine for me but I would prefer my XPATH since it is not dependent on index numbers `[2]`, `[4]` etc. So in future even if their web developer inserts one more `<p>` tag there my XPATH would still work. There are thousands (literally) of comments here suggesting people to not use regex for HTML parsing because of simple reason that regex cannot reliably parse a HTML. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: i understand, but my method /html/body/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/p[4]/text() is like a fastfood, you don't have to look into your html code, just open Mozilla, copy paste the xpath, and you're done

Comment: Agreed and as I said that Mozilla generated XPATH will work fine as well with current HTML source.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$subject = file_get_contents( 'http://www.lookupexpert.com/search_phone?phone_number=7322691678');
preg_match_all( '#<p class="location">(.*?)</p>#', $subject, $matches);
var_dump( $matches[1][1]);
```

This outputs:

```
string(14) "OCEAN GATE, NJ"
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WGLLQV)

Comment: yes ... but when you try with $subject = file_get_contents("http://lookupexpert.com/search_phone?phone_number=7322691678"); it gives you string(8) "Location" .... Why is that?!?!

Comment: @RowMinds - Because it's matching the table header, which is also a `<p class="location">`. Change the `preg_match` call to `preg_match_all`, and throw out the first result. I'll update my post.

Comment: For your example, regex is easier and simpler. You could use xpath, but I doubt you'll really *need* it. Your use-case is simple enough to use a regex and be done.

Comment: What if `<p class="location">` becomes `<p id="loc" class="location">` tomorrow?

Comment: `#` are the delimiters for the regex - You chose the same delimiting character in your sample regex. And @anubhava, simple questions yield simple answers. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this XPath**

```
//p[@class='location']/text()
```

**or this RegEx**

```
(?<=<p class="location">)([^<>]+)(?=</p>)
```

**code**

```
preg_match_all('%(?<=<p class="location">)([^<>]+)(?=</p>)%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: test.txt:12: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 2

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC45oW6TD6fwQHjKmK1wIfZjco-YNnQfmU&sensor in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 2

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 2

Warning: simplexml_l .................... and so on ... its not properly validated ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
$string = '<p class="location">OCEAN GATE, NJ</p>';
$pattern = '/<p class="location">(.*)<\/p>/';

$preg = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: same results 
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p class="location">Location</p>
            [1] => 1345
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Location
            [1] => 1365
        )

)